# Intermittent issue getting input

Tags: c++

Can someone explain to me what's wrong with this code? It works sometimes, i.e. if I input 5, 5, 5, -1 on the terminal, it'll return 15. But other times, it returns 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int input; 
    vector<int> input_vector;
    cout << "Enter -1 when done" << endl;;
    
    cout << "Your int: ";
    cin >> input;
    while (input != -1) {
        input_vector.push_back(input);
        cout << "Your int: ";
        cin >> input;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (auto i : input_vector) {
        cout << "i: " << input_vector[i] << endl;
        sum += input_vector[i];
    }

    cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what input do you provide and get that error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use a range-based notation `for (auto i : input_vector)` which gives for `i` the actual values stored in the array. But then you use it as `input_vector[i]`. This is wrong: `i` is the value of the element, not the index. So replace `input_vector[i]` by `i`.

```
for (auto i : input_vector) {
    cout << "i: " << i << endl;
    sum += i;
}
```

Note that now you don't have the index any more, but for calculating a sum you don't need that.